# Portable Program that will send files to FTP server whenever I save

Tags: upload, filezilla, ftp

I'm doing a PHP web project and do a lot of saving to check that the code I'm writing hosts properly on our target environment.

I do a lot of saving and thus, when I save I wish it would just automatically FTP the files up to the server so I could just hit refresh on the page I want.

Is there a configuration of Filezilla or a Portable App version of a program that can do this (I don't have admin. rights on the computer I'm working on to install stuff.)?

Comment: If you are using Windows, you can open the FTP server as a network share and edit the files directly on the server.

Answer (score 2):

### Local PHP - on a stick

Install a portable PHP + MySQL environment on a USB stick you plug in to your development computer. E.g [Portable WampServer](http://www.pendriveapps.com/uniform-server-wamp-portable-website-server-package/). You can then test each update locally. You only need to FTP to your server when you have finished testing all the changed files in your project.

Comment: +1 - Except I'd suggest going with [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) instead of WampServer.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison: Ahh yes, I didn't know about [XAMPP USB Lite](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#646).

Comment: I did that originally, but there were 2 issues with that:
1) I had to continually re-write the file paths for includes due to Windows vs Unix (backslashes into forward slashes)
2) The current version of XAMPP doesn't match the deployment environment. This was brought to my attention when I got a GD error that showed up on the deployment environment but couldn't be duplicated on XAMPP because it is newer.

Comment: @Zigu, 1) the Windows API (as used by Windows ports of Apache, PHP etc) will accept forward slashes - it is only the Command Prompt that doesn't. Are you certain this is a problem? 2) Version mismatch is a problem, true.

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a batchfile wrapper around putty's pscp tool?  It's command-line driven and should be pretty straight forward. (Same could be done with WinSCP I imagine).

If you need to send files that are changed, you could use powershell to find them and the call pscp